# Djanog app quickbooks authorization page from client

Tags: python-3.x, django, oauth-2.0, quickbooks-online

how can I have a page in my app in which I ask my clients to authorize my app to have access to my clients quickbooks?

I m ok to connect to quickbooks in my app but I add manually clients credentials. I would like to have template in my Django app that handle this. My client will use this template to authorize my app to have access to QBO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBooks AuthClient has method `get_authorization_url()` which can generate auth URL for your app. Having this URL, you can redirect user to QuickBooks OAuth flow, which will redirect back to your web-site (URL you defined in settings) with `auth_code` as GET variable in URL. You can convert it to `auth_token` and save it to database.

Here you can find official documentation from QuickBooks:

- [Get started](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/get-started)
- [Build your first app](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/build-your-first-app)
- [python-quickbooks](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks/) library with code examples